# Apache2 still running PHP5 when PHP7 is installed

Tags: php

I set up a apache2 server, and it was running PHP5. I have followed this guide to install PHP7:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-php-7-on-ubuntu-14-04

Now, when I run php -v I get:

```
PHP 7.0.30-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: May  2 2018 13:00:43) ( NTS )
```

However, when I made a webpage on apache and echoed phpinfo(), I got:

```
PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.24
```

How can I tell apache2 to use PHP7?

Comment: Check [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/428800/how-do-i-tell-apache-which-php-to-use)

Answer (score 1):

`php -v` gives you the version of php-cli, to enable it in apache2 you have to run these commonads

```
sudo a2dismod php5
sudo a2enmod php7.0
sudo service apache2 restart
```

then check phpinfo() for the version. it should change.

Answer (score 0):

reading more in depth the article, many people said to encouter difficulties when running `$sudo apt-get install php7.0`because of "unmet dependencies". Execute the following `$sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0-mysql php7.0-curl php7.0-json` to be sure yoo have everything needed.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You installed new version of php for your apache2 but you will need to disable/remove sym-links to old php5.x and enable/add sym-links for new php7.x. @Rhythm Shahriar pointed that out.

But here is the full steps taken and edited from https://askubuntu.com/questions/760907/upgrade-to-16-04-php7-not-working-in-browser

To configure php7.x to run with your apache2 server you need to do some configuration:

**1. Make sure you remove any traces of php/php5.x**

```
cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled
ls -la
```

The output should not contain any `php5.x.conf` or `php5.x.load`, but if it does, do the following:

```
# this is the proper way of disabling modules
sudo a2dismod php5.x

# run this only if the above command didn't remove the php5.x sym-links
sudo rm php5.x.load
sudo rm php5.x.conf
```

Now add the `php7.x.conf` and `php7.x.load` instead:

```
# this is the proper way of enabling modules
sudo a2enmod php7.x

# run this only if the above command didn't create the php7.x sym-links
sudo ln -s php7.x.conf ../mods-available/php7.x.conf
sudo ln -s php7.x.load ../mods-available/php7.x.load
```

The output of `ls -la php*` should look like this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Apr 15 03:55 php7.x.conf -> ../mods-available/php7.x.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Apr 15 03:55 php7.x.load -> ../mods-available/php7.x.load
```

After dealing with the modules we now come to the `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled` directory. Remove any traces of php/php5.x here as well by `sudo rm <name>`

Then, if needed do:

```
# the proper way of enabling configs
sudo a2enconf php7.x-cgi
sudo a2enconf php7.x-fpm

# do those commands only if the above didn't work out
sudo ln -s php7.x-cgi.conf ../conf-available/php7.x-cgi.conf
sudo ln -s php7.x-fpm.conf ../conf-available/php7.x-fpm.conf
```

The output of `ls -la php*` should look like this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 Apr 21 17:00 php7.x-cgi.conf -> ../conf-available/php7.x-cgi.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 Apr 21 17:01 php7.x-fpm.conf -> ../conf-available/php7.x-fpm.conf
```

**2. Restarting Apache2**

Before restarting Apache make sure to clean out the Apache error.log then restart:

```
sudo su
> /var/log/apache2/error.log
exit
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Now check the `error.log` by issuing `cat /var/log/apache2/error.log | less` (piping through less enables you to easy scroll up and down, `q` exits the output).

If your `error.log` contains many (and I literally mean a **heap** of) some `MIBS not found` do the following:

```
sudo apt install libsnmp-dev
sudo net-snmp-config --snmpconfpath
sudo apt-get install snmp snmp-mibs-downloader
sudo su
> /var/log/apache2/error.log
exit
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Then check again the `error.log` it now should only contain 3 lines:

```
[Sat Apr 23 01:39:07.504005 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1647] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Apr 23 01:39:08.685774 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 9590] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_perl/2.0.9 Perl/v5.22.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Apr 23 01:39:08.685938 2016] [core:notice] [pid 9590] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

***Your Apache with php7.x should now be properly configured. Tested working on Ubuntu 16.04 upgraded from php5.6 to latest as of today php7.3***